# Converting mmddyy10. to date9.

Tags: date, sas

I am trying to convert **mmddyy10.** dates i.e. **11/11/2013** to **date9.** i.e. **11NOV2013** and
constantly failing. Any suggestions.

```
data dates; 
 my_birthday = '11/11/2013';  
 date1 = input(input(my_birthday,date9.),date9.); 

 put date1 ; 
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
put(input(my_birthday,mmddyy10.),date9.)
```

If you really want it to be character.  `INPUT` converts characters to a number, `PUT` converts a number to characters.  Here, your characters are like `MMDDYY10.`, so you `INPUT` with `MMDDYY10` to get to a number, and then `PUT` to the format you like (`DATE9`).

Think of it as translating.  `11/11/2013` is french, `11NOV2013` is spanish, and the number behind it is english.  `INPUT` needs a french->english dictionary, so `MMDDYY10.`; `PUT` needs an english to spanish dictionary, so `DATE9.`

Better: store it as a real date (number) and just use a format so it's easy to swap back and forth.

Comment: Joe , Its going inside a query where it will hit some db2 table and some sas native tables, so I might have to keep it like that. thanks again.

Comment: the SAS/ACCESS to DB2 should handle the date conversion between SAS values and DB2 date values.